# finding the size of integer without using sizeof

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sizeof

I'm trying to find the size of integer without using sizeof function. I wrote something like this but it doesn't work properly. It outputs 1.
Please correct me. Here is my code.

```
int intSize() {
 int intArray[10];
 int *intPtr1;
 int *intPtr2;
 intPtr1 = intArray;
 intPtr2 = intPtr1 + 1;
 return intPtr2-intPtr1;
}
```

Comment: `intPtr2 = intPtr1 + 1;` then obviously, `intPtr2-intPtr1` will be 1

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function.

Comment: You need to cast pointers to `char*` to do it this way.

Comment: **Why?** What's wrong with using the language feature provided exactly for the purpose?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: You mean, to `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @barakmanos: No, I mean to `char*`.

Comment: Try `(unsigned long int)intPtr2 - (unsigned long int)intPtr1`

Comment: @GMichael casting pointer to integer is not allowed on certain compilers, and it may lead to undefined behaviour on some platforms

Comment: @DenisSheremet Yes, I know. I've already seen a much better answer from R Sahu

Answer (score 2):

Cast the pointer to `char*` before using pointer arithmetic.

```
int intSize() {
  int intArray[10];
  char* ptr1 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(intArray);
  char* ptr2 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(intArray+1);
  return ptr2-ptr1;
}
```

Comment: There is no direct access to intArray, so you may just replace it with `int* intArray = NULL`

Comment: @DenisSheremet: No, computing `(int*)(0) + 1` is UB. But the array is overkill. Only a single `int` variable is needed.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Afaik, accessing memory at `(int*)(0) + 1` is UB, but computing is not. May you reference to a language standart?

Comment: @DenisSheremet: I'm sure you can find it, if language for it exists. Infamously, C++98 claimed in a non-normative note that it stated somewhere that dereferencing a nullpointer was UB, but there was no such language anywhere. C++11 attempted to fix it but it was still a bit messy & unclear. I'm not sure of the status with C++14 and the C++17 draft. But  the **intent** is that even computing it, in a potentially evaluated context, is UB.

Comment: @DenisSheremet, I couldn't find anything in the C++11 standard to substantiate or refute your claim.

Comment: I would say the UB comes from the fact there would be have possible overflow (in general case) with pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score -1):

Use unit8_t if you want it to work across all platforms; its guaranteed to be a byte.

```
  int intSize() {
      int base = 0;
      return reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&base + 1) - reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&base);
  }
```

Comment: **−1** `uint8_t` is not guaranteed to be a byte. It's [guaranteed to be an octet, if it exists for a given platform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). `char` is guaranteed to be a byte.

Comment: char - type for character representation which can be most efficiently processed on the target system (has the same representation and alignment as either signed char or unsigned char, but is always a distinct type). Multibyte characters strings use this type to represent code units. The character types are large enough to represent 256 different values (in order to be suitable for storing UTF-8 encoded data) (since C++14) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: uint8_t is guaranteed to be 8 bits.  char is not.

Comment: Integer type with a width of exactly 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits.
For signed types, negative values are represented using 2's complement.
No padding bits. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/

Comment: @JoshHomann Notice that some types are optional (and thus, with no portability guarantees). (Below from your article)