# calculate size of an integer/any data type without using `sizeof(*type)`?

Tags: c++, algorithm, integer

Is there a method to calculate the size of a variable without using any predefined functions?
I read somewhere that it can be done using bit manipulation, but I'm not sure.

This is an answer ([finding the size of integer without using sizeof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373157/finding-the-size-of-integer-without-using-sizeof)), but I want a better approach in C++ which shall be algorithmic (without using a predefined function.

Comment: In case it helps any, `sizeof` is an operator, not a function. It can be used without parentheses, as in `sizeof int`

Comment: What do you mean by "algorithmic", or "better"? In what way does the answer you cite fail to satisfy your (heretofore unstated) requirements?

Comment: You can use the dereferenced pointer for typesize along with `sizeof` without using the `type`, e.g. `struct foo *f = malloc (sizeof *f);`

Comment: Why do you want to ignore the one language construct that is designed to give you exactly what you need?  I don't understand.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `sizeof` cannot be used without parenthesis when the operand is a type. It is only allowed if the operand is an expression. As such, `sizeof int` is ill-formed, but `int i; sizeof i;` is OK.

Comment: Perhaps `int i; (char *)(&i + 1) - (char*)&i;`  Maybe too much like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40373210/2410359)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, That's a nice answer. I was expecting something like that. I would love, if you put it in answer, and I shall mark it as accepted.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, The question is completely self-sufficient and I have not claimed `sizeof` be a function anywhere. "Predefined functions" wasn't referring to sizeof, it was for description that I want a step-by-step approach. Eg.: Instead of using `binary_search` from STL, how would I implement it (algorithmically). Plus, 'better' means an easy approach (interpretable) to find the size.

Comment: @AnubhavSachan If [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63626867/calculate-size-of-an-integer-any-data-type-without-using-sizeoftype?noredirect=1#comment112513092_63626867)  applies, then post is really a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373157/finding-the-size-of-integer-without-using-sizeof).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I was expecting a bit manipulation answer too (which is quite clearly mentioned in the question). But since, everyone here has "researched" then your answer must be accepted as correct.

Comment: The easy approach to find the size, in bytes, of any type is to apply `sizeof` operator to that type. Why again is this not suitable for your needs? What kind of algorithm do you envision? The compiler knows for sure how large every type is, and there's an easy way to ask it.

Comment: Bit manipulation is perhaps something you can do with an integer, but not generally with "any data type".

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I usually use `sizeof` but this was asked in an interview, hence, I would love to know a workaround (Motive behind using Stackoverflow). Can you tell me how can you calculate the size for an integer (leave the rest) using bits?

Comment: [Something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/fhPj6d)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a method to calculate the size of a variable without using any predefined functions?

Yes. You can use the `sizeof` operator. `sizeof` is not a function.

> calculate size of an integer/any data type without using `sizeof(*type)`?

If you have an object of such type, then pointer arithmetic is one way. There is an example of this in the page linked in the question. But there is generally no need to use such hack.

Another - limited - trick is to use `std::numeric_limits` (although its implementation probably internally uses `sizeof`). This works only with integer types (assuming no padding bits; will work for unsigned integers, may in theory fail with signed ones):

```
using T = int; // example
static_assert(std::is_integral_v<T> &&
              std::has_unique_object_representations_v<T>);
auto size = ( std::numeric_limits<T>::digits
            + std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed) / CHAR_BIT;
```

> but I want a better approach

`sizeof` operator is the better approach, compared to the tricks mentioned above.